# todonotes raise error of Tex capacity

Tags: sharelatex, acm, todonotes

I am using ACM SIG CHI proceedings template on ShareLatex, and I want to let co-authors to comment my writing.

Therefore, I used `todonotes` package. However, when I added `\todo{some comments}`, the error `Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`. I can use `todo[inline]` but it is not exact what I want.

Is there a way to fix this problem and use `\todo` with ACM template (two columns).

Thanks a lot.

**Update**: add example

I created a public project here so you can see the error (with the latest version of SIG CHI format):

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/573d90accf381d4713eaa828

Comment: Without a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) it is near impossible to say why this is happening. Please provide one.

Comment: Would it be very hard for you to leave one simple link to prevent helpers from doing some research to reproduce *your* problem?

Comment: Downloading the template, unpacking it, adding a note, the error cannot be reproduced. Please provide a proper minimal working example.

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B, I totally agree. Currently there is a problem with copy paste on my Mac (it just stop working, I tried to kill pboard process but does not help) therefore I cannot copy the URL to the sample project. Will update ASAP.

Comment: That was using an old file `sigchi`. Get the current one from github!

Comment: I updated with the latest SIGCHI format, and the error is the same.

Comment: It is not on ShareLaTeX, where i just replaced the class in your example with the one from github.

Comment: Hello, I updated the latest file (in the question anyway) with the template from github, so it should be the latest version, and the error still appears

Comment: That file is from 2014, whereas http://sigchi.github.io/Document-Formats/ as well as the git repo are from a later date.

Comment: I downloaded the templates from http://sigchi.github.io/Document-Formats/ yesterday. How could it be out-of-date?

Comment: The download page is suggested by Github page at https://github.com/sigchi/Document-Formats (first section in README file)

Comment: Oh, my crap. Sorry, I changed to 2016 version and now can use \todo with [chi_draft] option. Thanks a lot for your time.